# How To Have A Section Fill The Entire Screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I was wondering how I can have different sections of a website fill the entire window.

For instance on this website by [Viraj Bindra](http://vrjbndr.com/).

In his experience sections, they take up the whole window. I do not know what to call it, is there a word for it? I was also wondering how he has an assist pull so it can perfectly fill the window?

I am sorry if this question is ambiguous. If you go to his website I think it will make more sense.

Comment: you can achieve that by setting a height for each section using javascript to be the same as window.innerHeight

Comment: Thank you! Unsure though how I would go about to write the script. Do I use the heights defined in my CSS to set them equal to the heights in the script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the behavior that you're referring to, but I would not use JavaScript, as CSS can do this with better performance. Plus, it's always a good idea to keep styling with styling whenever possible. Anyway, a simple solution would be to set the container element to full-height using `vh` units. Like so:

```
.fullheight-container {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Easy as that, without any complications / after-load jumpiness from JavaScript.